# Is there a way that I can have a python program open another one? [Python 3.7 chatroom]

Tags: python

I've been making a simple chatroom in python and I'm having trouble getting it to  run outside of the IDE, the code works but not when I export the multiple scripts that I have as .exe's
The scripts I have are
server.py
client.py
and
main.py
main just imports client because it rejects the computer if I try to run it off client alone for some reason. I tried to incorporate the scripts into each other but server doesn't allow anything else to be run inside it and I don't know if it would work inside of client.
The thing that I'm trying to do is get it so that it would run and work for someone that I just gave the program to, without them having to go through all the steps which is launch server.py then open main.py
The server works fine as an exe but main and client just open and close themselves immediately.
And my goal is to have it run entirely as a .bat or a console based exe file.

This is what the program would look like when open.
[Start screen of main/client.py][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PIey.png

here is the server.py script (I've changed the port numbers and such as an example)

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import subprocess

# server's IP address
SERVER_HOST = "1.2.3.4"
SERVER_PORT = 0000 # port
separator_token = "<SEP>" # separate client name and message

# initialize list/set of all connected client's sockets
client_sockets = set()
# create a TCP socket
s = socket.socket()
# make the port as reusable port
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
# bind the socket to the address we specified
s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
# listen for upcoming connections
s.listen(5)
print(f"[*] Listening as {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")

def listen_for_client(cs):
    """
    This function keep listening for a message from `cs` socket
    Whenever a message is received, broadcast it to all other connected clients
    """
    while True:
        try:
            # keep listening for a message from `cs` socket
            msg = cs.recv(0000).decode()
        except Exception as e:
            # client no longer connected
            # remove it from the set
            print(f"[!] Error: {e}")
            client_sockets.remove(cs)
        else:
            # if we received a message, replace the <SEP> 
            # token with ": " for nice printing
            msg = msg.replace(separator_token, ": ")
        # iterate over all connected sockets
        for client_socket in client_sockets:
            # and send the message
            client_socket.send(msg.encode())


while True:
    # we keep listening for new connections all the time
    client_socket, client_address = s.accept()
    print(f"[+] {client_address} connected.")
    # add the new connected client to connected sockets
    client_sockets.add(client_socket)
    # start a new thread that listens for each client's messages
    t = Thread(target=listen_for_client, args=(client_socket,))
    # make the thread daemon so it ends whenever the main thread ends
    t.daemon = True
    # start the thread
    t.start()
    
    

# close client sockets
for cs in client_sockets:
    cs.close()
# close server socket
s.close()
```

and here is client.py (again changed numbers and ports)

```
import socket
import random

from pyfiglet import figlet_format
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime
from colorama import Fore, init, Back

# initiate colours
init()
# available colours
colors = [Fore.BLUE, Fore.CYAN, Fore.GREEN, Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX, 
    Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX, Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX, Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX, 
    Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX, Fore.LIGHTRED_EX, Fore.LIGHTWHITE_EX, 
    Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX, Fore.MAGENTA, Fore.RED, Fore.WHITE, Fore.YELLOW
]

client_color = random.choice(colors)

SERVER_HOST = "127.2.3.4"
SERVER_PORT = 0000 # server's port
separator_token = "<SEP>" # separates client name and message

# initialize TCP socket
s = socket.socket()
print(f"[*] Connecting to {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}...")
# connect to the server
s.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))

print(figlet_format('M o n t y', font='colossal', justify='center') + figlet_format('C R', font='alligator2', justify='center'))
print("[+] Connected.")
print("Type and enter 'q' to exit the program any time")
# prompt the client for a name
name = input("Enter your name: ")

def listen_for_messages():
    while True:
        message = s.recv(0000).decode()
        print("\n" + message)

# make a thread that listens for messages to this client & print them
t = Thread(target=listen_for_messages)
# make the thread daemon so it ends whenever the main thread ends
t.daemon = True
# start the thread
t.start()

while True:
    # input message we want to send to the server
    to_send =  input()
    # a way to exit the program
    if to_send.lower() == 'q':
        break
    # add the datetime, name & the color of the sender
    date_now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
    to_send = f"{client_color}[{date_now}] {name}{separator_token}{to_send}{Fore.RESET}"
    # finally, send the message
    s.send(to_send.encode())

# close the socket
s.close()
```

thank you in advance.